# How to change cygwin hostname

Tags: php, cygwin, hostname

I'm just searching for a way to change the default Cygwin host name. I need to change the `Admin@deluxe ~` part and replace it with something else.

Comment: It seems like you're asking two questions here: how to change the host name on Cygwin, and how to run a PHP script. You'll have much better luck if you ask your separate questions as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin reads the host name from Windows. On Windows 7 (instructions will be similar for other versions of Windows) you can change this by doing the following:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Click System and Security
3. Click System
4. Under "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings", click Change Settings
5. Next to "To rename this computer…" click "Change…"
6. Enter your desired host name in the "Computer name" box then click OK twice.

To simply change the Bash prompt, however, you don't need to jump through those hoops. The Bash prompt is controlled by the `PS1` environment variable, and there're extensive instructions in the [Bash man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) under "Prompting".

For example, to temporarily set your Bash prompt to `Howdy>`, you can use the following command:

```
PS1='Howdy> '
```

While to set it whenever you restart the Bash shell, use the following to add it to your `.bashrc` file (which is run whenever Bash is started).

```
echo 'PS1="Howdy> "' >>~/.bashrc
```